# Tracking ActionCable performance on Rails and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, heroku, actioncable

I'm running a Rails 5.2 app on Heroku which relies heavily on ActionCable. 
ActionCable is being mounted in the routes with

```
mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

My issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to do performance profiling for action cable channel actions. The majority of my app runs through action cable which seems to be creating a deadzone for performance profiling. My questions are:

1. Is there a third party service which allows me to track the performance of action cable actions (CPU usage, memory usage, response times etc.)? From what I understand popular solutions like Scout and Skylight don't have this functionality.
2. Is actioncable performance currently displayed in any way on the heroku metrics dashboard? I can't figure out if the web dyno metrics are displaying anything from action cable

Thanks in advance!

Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [New Relic Ruby Agent](https://blog.newrelic.com/product-news/rails-5-support-ruby-agent/) includes support for ActionCable. ActionCable transactions are displayed on the Transaction Monitoring page in New Relic alongside normal transactions:

[image: ActionCable transactions]

You can also view breakdowns of ActionCable methods and transaction traces for ActionCable requests that exceed your threshold:

[image: ActionCable transaction breakdown]

If you prefer not to use a paid product then there is an extremely simple, rudimentary gem called [resource_monitor](https://github.com/WriteCodeEveryday/resource_monitor) that displays system statistics like CPU and memory usage, but does not provide instrumentation like New Relic and other code-level performance monitoring applications do.